# Finding the locus: Given a line segment $AB$ and an angle $\alpha$ such that $0$°$<\alpha<180$°, find the locus of points P such that $APB=\alpha$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

I speculate that the locus will be the arc $\Lambda$  of circumcircle of $\Delta ACB$ with equal base angles $\angle CAB=\angle CBA=\frac{180^\circ-\alpha}{2}$ which lies on the same side as $C$ and the arc $\lambda$ congruent to it and symmetric with respect to $AB$. To visualize it,
[image]

Proof: Let $P$ be any point on $\Lambda \cup \lambda$. Clearly, $\angle APB=\alpha$ (Angle in the same segment).
Thus, every point $P$ on $\Lambda \cup \lambda$ is in the locus of points $P$ such that $\angle APB=\alpha$.

Let $P$ be a point such that $\angle APB=\alpha$. If so, then draw a circum-circle through $\Delta ABP$ and construct $\Delta AXB$ on $AB$ on the same side as $P$ such that $AX=AC$ and $\angle XAB=\angle CAB=\frac{180^\circ-\alpha}{2}$. It is not difficult to see that $\Delta ACB=\Delta AXB$ or $X=C$ or $P$ lies on the circumcircle of $\Delta ACB$. Hence, proved.
Note:C is the vertex of the isosceles triangle with base AB and base angles $\frac{180−α}{2}$.
Is this correct? Or does it have a glitch?

Comment: You talk about $C$ but nowhere define it. Whether the locus is both arcs or just one of them depends on whether your $\alpha$ is an oriented angle or not.

Comment: C is the vertex of the isosceles triangle with base $AB$ and base angles $\frac{180-\alpha}{2}$.

Comment: That belongs into the question, not as a comment.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: Looks better now (+1). The idea is right, but whether "*it is not difficult to see that ...*" is sufficient or needs more elaboration, depends on the context i.e. the expectations of whoever posed the question to you.